# Contract for hosted software

Tags: saas, contract, hosted, hosted-app

I've finally found a client for my hosted software - the first time I've ever sold software.  I want both parties to sign a contract specifying things like expected uptime, payment schedules, etc., so that no one feels like they've been cheated, but I'm not a lawyer and can't really afford one right now.  Does anyone know how to start with this process?

TIA.

Comment: If you live in the US, check with your local bar association.  Consulting a lawyer may be less expensive than you think.  Not consulting a lawyer may be a whole lot more expensive than you think.

Comment: what's the value of the sale?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When writing a **legal agreement** of that type, it is hard to give any other answer than "**get a lawyer**."

Answer (score 0):

Repeat exactly what you have just said to us to your customer. Start a conversation, and take it from there.

In my experience, they will likely appreciate your openness and desire to make sure all parties interests are protected.

If they are large, they may have contracts/SLAs that you can use as a template, and if they are small they may agree to settle for some very simple terms. There are also many templates on the internet available for a small charge.

But as Robert says, you really shouldn't sign **anything** legally binding without some input from a qualified solicitor. Further, it can't be your run of the mill high street lawyer either. You really need somebody that deals with software/SLA's on a regular basis. Sadly in my experience these people are never cheap.

Allen